# How to calculate next birthday using Joda time libaray

Tags: java, date, time, android-jodatime

I have two dates in format like 
Date of birth suppose 1995/04/09 and current date 2016/07/24
so how can I get Months and Days remaining to next birthday

```
public String getNextBirthdayMonths() {
     LocalDate dateOfBirth = new LocalDate(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
     LocalDate currentDate = new LocalDate();

     Period period = new Period(dateOfBirth, currentDate);
     PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                              .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" Months ")
                              .appendDays().appendSuffix(" Days ")
                              .printZeroNever().toFormatter();

        String nextBirthday = periodFormatter.print(period);
        return "" + nextBirthday;
}
```

Please anyone help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## java.time

The Joda-Time team advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### Parsing

Your input value is close to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. We can convert it by replacing the slashes with hyphens.

```
String input = "1995/04/09".replace ( "/" , "-" );
```

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default for parsing and generating strings representing date-time values. So no need to define a formatting pattern. The `LocalDate` class can directly parse the input.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse ( input );
```

### `MonthDay`

All we need for recurring annual events such as birthday is the month and the day. The java.time classes include [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) for this purpose.

```
MonthDay monthDayOfBirth = MonthDay.from ( dateOfBirth );
```

Next we need the current date. Note that while a `LocalDate` does not *store* a time zone internally, we need a time zone to determine today’s date. For any given moment the date varies around the world by time zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight is a new day in Paris while still “yesterday” in Montréal.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );
int year = today.getYear ();
```

With the current year in hand, we can create that year’s birthday by asking the `MonthDay` instance.

```
LocalDate nextBirthday = monthDayOfBirth.atYear ( year );
```

Verify that determined date is indeed the *next* birthday. May have already passed, in which case we need to add a year.

```
if ( nextBirthday.isBefore ( today ) ) {
    nextBirthday = nextBirthday.plusYears ( 1 );
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | dateOfBirth: " + dateOfBirth + " | today: " + today + " | nextBirthday: " + nextBirthday );
```

> input: 1995-04-09 | dateOfBirth: 1995-04-09 | today: 2016-07-24 | nextBirthday: 2017-04-09

### `Period`

Now we move on to calculate the time to elapse until that next birthday. The [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class represents a span of time in terms of years, months and days.

```
 Period period = Period.between ( today ,  nextBirthday ).normalized ();
```

We can interrogate for the months part and the days part.

```
int months = period.getMonths();
int days = period.getDays();
```

### Strings

As for reporting these values in a string, for data exchange and possibly for some reports to humans, I suggest using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for a span of time not tied to the timeline: [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). The `P` marks beginning, and `T` separates the hours-minutes-seconds part (if any). So one month and six days would be `P1M6D`.

The `Period` and `Duration` classes in java.time use this format by default in their `toString` methods.

```
String output = period.toString();
```

Or create your own string.

```
String message = months + " Months " + days + " Days";
System.out.println ( "period: " + period.toString () + " | message: " + message );
```

> period: P8M16D | message: 8 Months 16 Days

I wish I knew a way to use `DateTimeFormatter` to automatically localize to a human language and cultural norms specified by a `Locale` as we can with other java.time types. But this does not seem to be possible with `Period` and `Duration` objects, unfortunately.

### `TemporalAdjuster`

It might be possible to package this code up into a class implementing [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html). Then you could use it with the simple `with` syntax.

```
LocalDate nextBirthday = dateOfBirth.with( MyTemporalAdjusters.nextRecurringMonthDay( myYearMonth ) );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

As per your question, You want to calculate the next birthday using Joda.
The below code will help you to give the coming birthday months.

```
   LocalDate dateOfBirth = new LocalDate(1995, 4, 9);
   LocalDate currentDate = new LocalDate();
   // Take birthDay  and birthMonth  from dateOfBirth 
   int birthDay = dateOfBirth.getDayOfMonth();
   int birthMonth = dateOfBirth.getMonthOfYear();
   // Current year's birthday
   LocalDate currentYearBirthDay = new LocalDate().withDayOfMonth(birthDay)
                        .withMonthOfYear(birthMonth);
   PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime().withYearsRemoved();
   PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" Months ").appendDays()
        .appendSuffix(" Days ").printZeroNever().toFormatter();
   if (currentYearBirthDay.isAfter(currentDate)) {
       Period period = new Period(currentDate, currentYearBirthDay,monthDay );
       String currentBirthday = periodFormatter.print(period);
       System.out.println(currentBirthday );
   } else {
        LocalDate nextYearBirthDay =currentYearBirthDay.plusYears(1);
        Period period = new Period(currentDate, nextYearBirthDay ,monthDay );
        String nextBirthday = periodFormatter.print(period);
        System.out.println(nextBirthday);
   }
```

Output:

> 8 Months 16 Days

Comment: This will crash if the DOB was on the 29th Feb on a leap year and the current year is not a leap year. org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 29 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,28]

Comment: Yes. But during initialization you need to pass the correct date.

Answer (score 1):

I would find next birthday date

```
LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
LocalDate birthDate = new LocalDate(1900, 7, 12);

int age = new Period(birthDate, today).getYears();

LocalDate nextBirthday = birthDate.plusYears(age + 1);
```

Then count how long it left to that date in months and days

```
PeriodType monthsAndDays = PeriodType.yearMonthDay().withYearsRemoved();
Period leftToBirthday = new Period(today, nextBirthday, monthsAndDays);

PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" Months ")
        .appendDays().appendSuffix(" Days ")
        .toFormatter();

return periodFormatter.print(leftToBirthday);
```

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he/she would have come up with a similar solution on his/her own, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. As such, please provide context to your answer and/or code by explaining *how* and/or *why* it works.